# Embedding assembler within C++ acceptable?

Tags: c++, performance, assembly

If you're writing an application which is very latency sensitive what are the limits to embedding assembler within C++ functions (and using the C++ function calls normally), like so:

```
inline __int64 GetCpuClocks()
{

    // Counter
    struct { int32 low, high; } counter;

    // Use RDTSC instruction to get clocks count
    __asm push EAX
    __asm push EDX
    __asm __emit 0fh __asm __emit 031h // RDTSC
    __asm mov counter.low, EAX
    __asm mov counter.high, EDX
    __asm pop EDX
    __asm pop EAX

    // Return result
    return *(__int64 *)(&counter);

}
```

(The above function came from another SO post I saw)

Can you treat assembler-inlined functions like a **black box**? Could you easily retrieve a result from calculations performed in assembler? Are there dangers that you dont know what variables are currently in registers etc? Does it cause more problems than solve, or is it acceptable for specific small tasks?

(Assume your architecture is going to be fixed, and known)

EDIT I just found this, this is what I am hinting at:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15971/Using-Inline-Assembly-in-C-C

EDIT2 This is more aimed towards Linux and x86- its just a general C++/assembler question (or so i thought).

Comment: Are you specifically asking about Visual C++? I suppose other compilers might have other constraints.

Comment: @Robᵩ Nope, if anything I was aiming towards Linux, ICC and G++. I just grabbed the first assembler function I saw.

Comment: This might be slightly OT, but if a jump and a return does not incur too heavy penalties, consider writing the assembler in pure assembler (in a separate compile unit) to keep your code more portable. By avoiding inlining, you can sometimes improve latency through more efficient cache utilization.

This is more significant on embedded platforms though.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to answer on the subquestion:

> Does it cause more problems than solve, or is it acceptable for specific small tasks?

It certainly does! Using inline assembler, you take the ability from the compiler to optimize the code. It cannot do partial expression substition or any other fancy optimization. It is really, really hard to produce code which is better than what the compiler emits with -O3. And as a bonus, the code gets even better with the next compiler release (presuming that the next compiler release doesn't break it ;) ).

Compilers usually grasp a more wider scope than human brains ever could (or should, to ensure sanity), being able to inline the right function at the right place, to do a partial expression substitution which makes code more efficient. Things you would never do in ASM because your code becomes unreadable as hell.

As an anecdotal reference, I'd like to [this post](http://torvalds-family.blogspot.de/2009/08/programming.html) by Linus Torvalds, relating to the git implementation of SHA1, which outperforms the hand-optimized SHA1 in libcrypt.

In fact, I think the only reasonable use of inline assembler nowadays is calling processor instructions which are not available otherwise (the one you quoted is available, on linux for example as `clock_gettime`, at least if you're only after a high resolution time counter) or if you have to do things where you need to trick the compiler (for example during implementation of foreign function interfaces).

---

On the snippet and what others said. Especially with such functions you'll get a performance penalty. In inline asm, you have to be super-careful that the registers are kept in the state the compiler assumes them to be (push/pop, as above). While if you write the code normally, the compiler can take care and keep exactly those variables for which it makes sense in registers and those which do not fit on the stack.

Trust your compiler. It's smart. Most of the time. Invest the time you save by not using inline assembler in thinking about smart, fast algorithms and learning the relevant compiler switches (e.g. to enable SSE optimizations etc.).

Comment: Surely you could argue though, that a compiler cannot be amazing at everything. So to compensate for the wide range of cases it can handle, there are probably many areas where, for a small specific task a programmer could write fewer asm instructions?

Comment: @user997112 Which cases do you have in mind? Thinking about everything having to do with numerics, you probably won't be able to cut it. Also note that I swapped the reference, my original one actually included inline ASM.

Comment: I dont have anything in mind, but it would certainly be useful if it was possible to find out if there are any areas compilers are bad.

Comment: You can of course always look at the ASM output (most compilers have a command line flag to keep that around in the output directory) and compare to what you would've written. Make sure to do that with -O3. And good luck finding your code ;) [make sure to enable line annotations]

Comment: There are actually very few areas where people can outperform the compiler. The compiler you are using in the example has compiler intrinsics for all the "interesting" instructions we might need, including reading the performance counters of the CPU. One problem with inline assembly in a regular function is that is disturbs the compiler's optimizations of the surrounding code, making it hard to achieve a net gain. And, of course, asm code assures *zero* portability for the code.

Answer (score 1):

If the asm in question is pushing any registers it uses at the top then pops them at the bottom, I think you're safe not to worry about it.

In your example, these are the `__asm push EAX` and `__asm pop EAX` instructions.

The real answer, I suppose, is that you need to know enough about what the asm does to be sure you can treat it as a black box. :)

Comment: So basically make sure the state you start in is the state you finish in? What if you want to return a calculation from the assembler, how would you do that?

Comment: Yup, make sure you don't mess with the state. Returning the value will depend on the compiler, I think.